# How to remove select options for angular primeng dropdown

Tags: angular

I'm trying to remove an item from a primeng drowdown

Init

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.characterList = [  
       {  
          "label":"Select character",
          "id":"-1"
       },
       {  
          "label":"New",
          "id":"0"
       },
       {  
          "id":32,
          "label":"Test2 "
       }
    ]
    this.character =  {  
              "id":"32",
              "label":"Test2 "
           }
}
```

The delete function

```
delete(): void {
    this.characterList.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (+this.character.id === +item.id)
        this.characterList.splice(index, 1);
    });
}
```

The html:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="characterList" [(ngModel)]="selectedCharacter" (onChange)="selectCharacter($event)" optionLabel="label"></p-dropdown>
<button pButton type="button" label="Delete character" (click)="delete()"></button>
```

But for some reason the p-dropdown isn't updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can suggest for a start adding `console.log(this.characterList)` at the bottom of the delete function, and observe if it indeed works fine.

Comment: I've done that, and this.characterlist is indeed updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to solve the problem. Here is the sample code that works:

HTML:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name" #drop></p-dropdown>
<button (click)="delete(drop)">DELETE</button>
```

JS

```
export class AppComponent {

cities: City[];
selectedCity: City;

constructor() {
    //An array of cities
    this.cities = [
        {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
        {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
        {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
        {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
        {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
    ];
    this.selectedCity = this.cities[0];
}
delete(drop):void{
  this.cities.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.name === this.selectedCity.name)
      this.cities.splice(index, 1);
  });
  this.selectedCity = this.cities[0];
      drop.options=this.cities;
    }
}
```

So it seems like you manually have to update the options for it to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm not sure why this works, but removing the `optionLabel="label"` fixes it, of course you can use a `ngModel` as well, which will fix it.

Comment: I've added the ngModel in the code above, but this does not fix it. Removing optionLabel from the code above stops the onchange from having any value in the $event

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is the following:  Add property: optionDisabled to your p-dropdown. Each option has a property "isDisabled", depending on the boolean value it will show disabled.
TS:

```
export interface SelectOption {  code: string;  name: string; isDisabled?: boolean;}
```

HTML:

```
<p-dropdown
    appendTo="body"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="code"
    placeholder="Select an option"
    [options]="column.options ? column.options : []"
    [(ngModel)]="row[column.labelCode]"     
    optionDisabled="isDisabled"> 

<ng-template let-option pTemplate="item"  >
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'disabled-option': option.isDisabled }">
        <option [value]="option.code">{{ option.name }}</option> 
    </div>
</ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Comment: This would work, but it's not correct since it doesn't remove the item from the list.